# Outlook mailItem convert to pdf portfolio using Outlook Add-In for Adobe Acrobat

Tags: c#, pdf, outlook, interop, office-interop

I am looking for a way I can right click on a mailItem in Outlook and click on Convert to pdf in the menu that would appear after right click and perform click on that convert to pdf menu option and get my pdf converted into a pdf portfolio.

**Important thing to remember before answering :**
I am looking for a conversion of ***Outlook mail to pdf portfolio not a simple pdf***. I am able to convert into a simple pdf, so that is not the thing I am looking for.

**Reason for searching this :** I am looking for a way to convert a mail into a pdf portfolio. A pdf portfolio is something from Adobe that is a kind of pdf inside a pdf with all attachments embbeded into the pdf and all emailIds are active links on the converted pdf which when clicked opens Outlook with all the attachments loaded and body and subject loaded to send to someone.

**What I tried ?**
I looked for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook documentation and read about Command Bars and Context Menu, but I could not find much articles that serves my purpose. I found a method that opens Categories dialog for a mailItem, but I want to open only the parent menu upon right click on the mailItem. Or is there any method available to call for mailItems add-in properties like we have for Send, Delete, Reply All etc.

**Possibility**
It is a challenge for me, but I thought upon implementing a CustomAction upon an Outook mailItem. But I could not figure out how to make the CustomAction right click the mail item. Or what will the code be for implementing such a custom action. Also I am not looking up at any other 3rd party libraries, but a feasilble solution with only Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.

Comment: With Adobe Acrobat Pro, if you select multiple emails, open the Acrobat ribbon, then choose "Selected Messages" then "Create New PDF", a PDF Portfolio will be created and each individual PDF within the portfolio will have the attachments from the message attached to the PDF. Were you looking to create a Portfolio from an individual message?

Comment: Hi joelgeraci , can you please share the psedo-code to do that via Acrobat ribbon ? And yes, I am looking to create portfolio from an individual mailItem in Interop.Outlook